# Multiple permalinks

Tags: permalinks

My blog uses the `/?p=378` permalink structure for some years. This isn't very helpful with Google Analytics, and I would like to change it to the `YEAR/MONTH/DAY/post-title` structure.

Is there a way to do this without losing backward compatability, so that old link will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old link (?p=378) will always work, and it will redirect to the "pretty" permalink.

Answer (score 1):

Like Devin said, the old link will always work and it will be redirected to the new link automatically by WordPress. Just make sure, that your .htaccess file is writable. Plus WordPress writes a reference to the short link in to the header section like this:

```
<link rel='shortlink' href='http://yoursite.com/?p=378' />
```